# Renaming Sitecore Media Item using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I want to rename or want to give the name to uploaded media item, but it always uploaded as unnamed as item(media) name. Following is my code.

```
    public static void UploadImage(int customerID,FileUpload fup)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            var options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
            {
                AlternateText =customerID.ToString(),
                FileBased = false,
                IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
                KeepExisting = false,
                Versioned = false,
                Destination = "/sitecore/media library/temp",
                Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master")
            };

            var filepath =  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fup.FileName);
            var creator = new MediaCreator();
            var mediaItem = creator.CreateFromStream(fup.PostedFile.InputStream, filepath, options);
            MediaItem myFile = mediaItem;

            myFile.Name = customerID.ToString(); // unable to give becasue it read only

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `.InnerItem.Editing.BeginEdit()` before renaming and `.InnerItem.Editing.EndEdit()` after renaming:

```
myFile.InnerItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
myFile.InnerItem.Name = customerID.ToString();
myFile.InnerItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

For more information see chapter `3.1.5 How to Place an Item in Editing Mode` here http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/content_api_cookbook-a4.pdf

Comment: I have tried.it gives compile error. because it shows read only.

Comment: See edited answer. Maybe `.InnerItem` will work for you.